# How do i make a nested container 100% width in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

I am trying to put one div on top of another and let the top one scroll, see http://www.bootply.com/z5B5YBWS5Y

just setting adding

```
body. home { width: 100%
```

doesn't work.

But i like the top div to be 100% width?

Comment: FYI: ok i had to delete col-md-12 and a container div see http://www.bootply.com/8DUwSgt7vs

Comment: Hi Alex, You are using `container` class inside another `container` class, this is not really how Bootstrap is meant to be set up. Have a read of this [Bootstrap link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L71qdsez/) to see how you could also do this. Using the class of `container-fluid` does what you want here as you will see in the fiddle.

Comment: @AngularJR but now all the .section-container divs have the text outlined on the left. If i change .section-container to .container then the text start with a margin on the left and has a margin on the right

Comment: Hi Alex. Have a look at the Bootstrap link (above) and read up on how BS is intended to be used. If you don't want padding left and right, what we do is override BS and use some custom css to clear the padding.